# Dell MD1220 RAID issue

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

This is probably going to be the stupidest question of the day, but I have to ask it because I can't seem to find an answer anywhere else.

With that said: It is my understanding that EMM 0 serves bays 0-11, and EMM 1 serves bays 12-23.

Is this a correct assumption?

What I am looking to do, is to build 2 separate arrays on one MD1220. If my assumption is right, then array 0 can be bays 0-11 and array 1 can be bays 12-23.

Can I do that?

The r710 server is using the PERC H810

Answer (score 2):

Not a stupid question at all - you likely just don't know where to find the information.

This is one of the supported "modes" of the enclosure, detailed in the [Hardware Owner's Manual](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powervault/powervault-md1220_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf), and is referred to as "split-bus mode".
Ensure that the small switch on the left side of the front of the enclosure is set DOWN (the pictures near the switch are somewhat intuitive), and power cycle the enclosure if the switch wasn't already set this way.

Once in split-bus mode, the TOP EMM (emm 0) actually manages the 2nd half of the drives, slots 12 to 23. The bottom EMM (emm 1) manages slots 0 to 11.

Comment: Hi Jim, and thank you for the answer. Can you tell me which mode I might need to accomplish sharing a set of drives across 2 servers?

Comment: If you want shared access to all the disks between two servers, this cannot be done with PERC RAID cards. You would end up with immediate data corruption. The only method I see to accomplish this (aside from purchasing an MD32xx array and connecting this to it as an expansion) is directly connecting to SAS6 HBAs instead of PERC cards, and using Storage Spaces with clustering to manage the drives. This is not a supported configuration for that enclosure though, so no guarantee it will be stable (though I've run it like this in my lab with decent results).

Comment: "Storage Spaces" is under the assumption you're using Windows (2012 minimum), though I would not recommend using legacy storage spaces (different from storage spaces direct) at all for business-critical data.You will either need a cluster, or some file system that is multi-host aware.

Answer (score 0):

I am the OP.

For some reason, I am not able to mark JimNim's answer as correct, because I lack the 50 points needed to accept the answer.

What's the point of allowing a person to post a question, if he doesn't have the authorization to accept an answer.

JimNim's answer is correct. Sorry I can't accept it.

Comment: OpenID login vs another account? maybe ask the support to merge your two accounts